# How should I go about scaling my physics body?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a physics body that needs the y scale to be 0.2. I have been using the rectangleOfSize property to define my physics body, but am not sure how to change the y scale of it. I had changed the y scale earlier in the code, and would like to know if there is an easier way to do this other than having to go into photoshop and create a new image. I will provide example code if anyone needs me to. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you need to use Photoshop when dealing with your physics body (you mentioned using the `rectangleOfSize` method) Do you mean scaling the sprite's texture? Or scaling both the sprite's texture and physics body? Or do I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I had already scaled the texture earlier in the code so just the physics body. When I test the app, the physics body has the original dimensions of the texture before being scaled.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, scaling the physicsBody in Spritekit would cause collisions to be bugged, I would recommend that you create a new physicsBody and assign it to the node instead.

As to change the yScale of the node, you can simply call this function

```
node.yScale = yourValue
```

Comment: How can I assign the SKSpriteNode to the physicsBody?

Comment: Try setting the physicsBody to nil and then initialize a new physicsBody. If this doesn't work you would probably have to create a new node with the new physicsBody and remove your old node.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an easier way! I recommend looking into `SKAction`. `SKAction` contains the class methods:

```
+ (SKAction *)scaleBy:(CGFloat)scale duration:(NSTimeInterval)sec;
+ (SKAction *)scaleXBy:(CGFloat)xScale y:(CGFloat)yScale duration:(NSTimeInterval)sec;
```